# Floating menu bars sticks to top when scrolling up, the one replaces the other jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll, instagram, fixed, menubar

The other day i found a javascript code, and i'm not good at javascript so i need some help.
The issue is that i would like to make a website kind of like the Instagram app. I have made an example with some pictures.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfprV.jpg

Imagine that the picture to the left is the first, middle second, and right third.

At my website i have a top with logo, and when header 1 reaches top it stays at top. I found a code about this, but i need that when you scroll, header 2 pushes header 1 away or moves in front of header 1.

This was the code i found, but it doesn't work when i have more than one bars that should be fixed at top when reaches top.

Thanks

```
    $(window).scroll(function(e) 
    var scroller_anchor = $(".scroller_anchor").offset().top; 
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= scroller_anchor && $('.scroller').css('position') != 'fixed') 
        {  
            $('.scroller').css({
                'background': 'white',
                'position': 'fixed',
                'top': '0px'
            });

            $('.scroller_anchor').css('height', '50px');
        } 
        else if ($(this).scrollTop() < scroller_anchor && $('.scroller').css('position') != 'relative') 
        {      

            $('.scroller_anchor').css('height', '0px');

            $('.scroller').css({
                'background': 'white',
                'position': 'relative'
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that each menu bar has to have it's top offset tracked separately.

Here is a simple solution that I believe does something at least similar to what you're looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/42Yuz/

The Code:

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
var menuTop1pos = $('#menutop1').offset().top;
var menuTop2pos = $('#menutop2').offset().top;

var stickToTop = function(){
    var winScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (winScrollTop >= menuTop1pos) {
            $('#menutop1').addClass('stickTop1st');
    } else {
            $('#menutop1').removeClass('stickTop1st');  
    }

    if (winScrollTop >= menuTop2pos) {  
            $('#menutop2').addClass('stickTop2nd');
    } else {
            $('#menutop2').removeClass('stickTop2nd');  
    }
};

stickToTop();

$(window).scroll(function() {
        stickToTop();
});
});
```

css

```
.stickTop1st {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    z-index:998;
    background-color:white;
}

.stickTop2nd {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    z-index:999;
    background-color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   // grab the initial top offset of the navigation 
      var stickyNavTop = $('.navigation').offset().top;
      
      // our function that decides weather the navigation bar should have "fixed" css position or not.
      var stickyNav = function(){
       var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // our current vertical position from the top
            
       // if we've scrolled more than the navigation, change its position to fixed to stick to top,
       // otherwise change it back to relative
       if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) { 
           $('.navigation').addClass('sticky');
       } else {
           $('.navigation').removeClass('sticky'); 
       }
   };

   stickyNav();
   // and run it again every time you scroll
   $(window).scroll(function() {
    stickyNav();
   });
  });
```